# Interaction testing using moles

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, moles

How can you verify interaction test using Moles. For example the following test is written using rhino mock. Can anyone please tell me how can I achive the same using moles? Is there anything like verify for moles?

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
    ILogger mockLogger = mocks.StrictMock<ILogger>();

    using(mocks.Record())
    {
        mockLogger .Log("this is my error");
    }

    MyClass mc = new MyClass (mockLogger);

    mc.MyFunc("abcd");
    mocks.Verify(mockLogger);
}



class MyClass
{

    private ILogger logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger logger)
    { this.logger = logger; }

    public void MyFunc(string str)
    {

        logger.log("this is my error");
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I use Moq for internal dependency and Moles for externalities (and unpleasant static stuff forced on me by others), so I might not be giving you the *best* way, but it's a way:

```
    [TestMethod, Owner("ebd"), TestCategory("Proven"), TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var myCalled = false;
        var myLogger = new SILogger();
        myLogger.LogString = (s) => myCalled = true;
        var myClass = new MyClass(myLogger);
        myClass.MyFunc("abcd");

        Assert.IsTrue(myCalled);
    }
```

Key idea here is "SILogger" which is your stub for ILogger.  You then set up instance behavior for it's "LogString" (which corresponds to your log(string) method.  You set it to callback your local variable and set it to true.  You then invoke the method that should invoke log, and you assert that your local is now true.

Again, I'd usually do this with Moq and used myStub.Verify() for this purpose, so it's possible that there's a slicker way to do this with moles that I'm not aware of.  Personally, I think Moles is much better suited for "mocking the unmockable", and I prefer a combination of Moq (for my own interfaces and classes) and Moq (for framework and externalities like File I/O, GUI, Db connections, etc).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I was thinking the same to capture a variable (flag) and set it to something to verify if the method has beed called or not. Do you think it's a bad idea / practice to use MOLES to mock internal dependencies aswell?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad practice, per se, but I worry about it in a multi-developer project because I think it can encourage bad design.  The fact that you can mock out *anything* leads people to conclusions like "cool, we can make everything static/singelton and still have unit tests".  Personally, I'd say that if you're having to mole you're own code and can't use something like Moq, that's a code smell.

Comment: Right.. I would try to make sure that even if we are using moles, we properly inject each dependency from outside.. Is there any other limitation you can think of when comparing moq vs moles??

Comment: Well, one thing I've found about Moles is that it's not at all light weight compared with Moq.  Moles actually generates entire Moles assemblies.  That takes up a lot of disk space, and makes the tests run a lot more slowly.  You also have to check in the Moles DLLs if you want other people to be able to run your tests.  So, there's good incentive to have separate Moles and Moq test assemblies, and may run the Moles ones as integration tests that execute less frequently.